# Gradle build declares a new Activity in the manifest without name, thus creating an error

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a new computer, I downloaded Android studio, I tried to retrieve a project I was working on with my previous computer, and when I open the project the Gradle Build declares a new Activity without a name and then says there this error :

```
Error:(30) error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name.
```

I tried deleting it, doing the Gradle Build again and it keep writing a new Activity in the Manifest file and then telling me there's an error, I have no clue where that could be from.

here is what my Android manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brumor.localear"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.0.0-alpha1" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.brumor.localear.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.brumor.localear." >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.brumor.localear.ArtistActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

see the activity 'android:name="com.brumor.localear."' line? It is the one generated when I do the Gradle build and causing the error in the very same Gradle build.

Comment: Edit the source AndroidManifest.xml file(s) you have, not the merged/generated one in `build` subdir.

Answer (score 0):

this line causing the error. you must provide an activity name which here missing
com.brumor.localear.**youractivityname**

```
<activity android:name="com.brumor.localear." >
```

make it with proper activity name or remove it

Answer (score 0):

I was actually editing the debug\AndroidManifest.xml instead of the main\AndroidManifest thanks to laalto for pointing me in the right direction !